# Create new Dataframe from Json element inside XML using Pyspark

Tags: pyspark, databricks

Hi I'm dealing with rather difficult XML file which I'm trying to reformat and clean for some processing. I've been using Pyspark to process the data into a dataframe and I am using `com.databricks.spark.xml` to read the file.

My Dataframe looks like this; Each field is JSON Formatted

```
+----------------+---------------------------------+
|      Identifier|                             Info|
+----------------+---------------------------------+
|  JSON          |     Json                        |
|                |                                 |
|                |                                 |
+----------------+---------------------------------+
```

This is a sample  value from the `Identifier` column

```
{
"Other": [
    {
        "_Type": "A",
        "_VALUE": "999"
    },
    {
        "_Type": "B",
        "_VALUE": "31086"
    },
    {
        "_Type": "C",
        "_VALUE": "13123"
    },
    {
        "_Type": "D",
        "_VALUE": "32323"
    },
    {
        "_Type": "E",
        "_VALUE": "2223"
    },
    {
        "_Type": "F",
        "_VALUE": "100"
    },
  ]
}
```

And this is how the `Info` Column looks like

```
{
"Demo": {
    "BirthDate": "2009-09-13",
    "BirthPlace": {
        "_VALUE": null,
        "_nil": true
    },
    "Rel": {
        "_VALUE": null,
        "_nil": true
    }

},
"EmailList": {
    "_VALUE": null,
    "_nil": true
},
"Name": {
    "LastName": "Marwan",
    "FullName": {
        "_VALUE": null,
        "_nil": true
    },
    "GivenName": "Saad",
    "MiddleName": null,
    "PreferredFamilyName": {
        "_VALUE": null,
        "_nil": true
    }
},
"OtherNames": {
    "_VALUE": null,
    "_nil": true
 }
}
```

I am trying to create a dataframe that looks like the following

```
+-------+--------+-----------+------------+------------+
|      F|       E|   LastName|  GivenName |   BirthDate|
+-------+--------+-----------+------------+------------+
```

Comment: Your title is confusing...

Comment: Please give us your sample XML

Comment: Can you give some examples of what you're currently trying to accomplish this?

Comment: @Sotos I will change it now. I can't post the XML file because it's classified data